# monkeyrunner browser drops characters

Tags: monkeyrunner

device.type('www.amazon.com') to the browser in the emulator drops the first 2 characters.  logcat shows the full string for 'type' but the first 2 chars are missing at the BrowserActivity.   device.press() for each individual character does the same thing...

```
[ 01-08 18:36:29.947 15335:0x3be7 D/MonkeyStub ]
translateCommand: type www.amazon.com


[ 01-08 18:36:33.175 15335:0x3be7 D/MonkeyStub ]
translateCommand: press KEYCODE_ENTER


[ 01-08 18:36:33.284 15353:0x3bf9 I/SearchDialog ]
Starting (as ourselves) #Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEARCH;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity;S.query=w.amazon.com;S.user_query=w.amazon.com;end
```

is there a trick to sending a string to the browser with monkeyrunner?

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence, could you edit it for clarity?